# Hide login page and use wp_login_form on ordinary pages

Tags: login, wp-login-form, admin-init

I would like to hide `site.com/wp-login.php` page but also to use `wp_login_form()` function where I want. Currently this function doesn't work if I hide login page with this code (it redirects to front page)

```
function go_away() {
        global $action;
        // redirect only if action is login (lost password action is ok)
        if($action === 'login') {
           wp_redirect(site_url());
           exit();
        }
}
add_action( 'login_init' , 'go_away' );
add_action( 'admin_init' , 'go_away' );
```

And code for login in `front-page.php` or in `sidebar.php` is this

```
wp_login_form(
    array(
    'redirect' => site_url( '/wp-admin/' )
));
```

How can I make `wp_login_form` work while hiding login page? Because currently this wp_login_form just keeps redirecting me to front page.

Comment: Have you tried blocking access to wp-login by htaccess? Just redirect it to your custom login page.

Comment: There is not any security benefit of hiding/blocking wp-login.php and using wp login from anywhere else; both are same form withh same security rules.